# ggplot problem with autocorrelation, one line/variable doesnt scale to 1 at lag 0. But the data shows that it's correlation is 1 at lag 0

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image: My ggplot of autocorrelation]

[image: My correlation values, the red line is defined as Kryds_BNP_BNP]

The code im using:

```
p11 <- ggplot(Autokor)+
  geom_line(aes(x=Lag, y=0))+
  stat_smooth(aes(y=Kryds_HP_HP, x=Lag, color = "HUSPRIS"), formula = y ~ s(x, k = 11), method = "gam", se = FALSE) +
  stat_smooth(aes(y=Kryds_RENTE_RENTE, x=Lag, color = "RENTE"), formula = y ~ s(x, k = 11), method = "gam", se = FALSE) +   
  stat_smooth(aes(y=Kryds_BNP_BNP, x=Lag, color = "BNP"), formula = y ~ s(x, k = 11), method = "gam", se = FALSE) +
  stat_smooth(aes(y=Kryds_KREDIT_KREDIT, x=Lag, color = "KREDIT"), formula = y ~ s(x, k = 11), method = "gam", se = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",") ,limits = c(-1, 1), breaks=round(seq(min(-1), max(1), by = 0.5),1)) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",") ,limits = c(-6, 6), breaks=round(seq(min(-6), max(6), by = 1),1)) +
  labs(title = "Autokorrelationer", x="Lag", y="Korrelation", caption = "", color=NULL)+ theme(legend.position="bottom") + theme(panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank()) + th
```

My problem is that the values shows that the red line (BNP) should have a top at correlation value 1, at lag 0, but in the ggplot BNP top is close to 0.4

Comment: Have you tried plotting a `geom_line()` instead of the `stat_smooth()`? My guess is that the smoothing is too aggressive to approach 1 at lag = 0.

Comment: It solved the problem, thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you add the solution as an answer, and Accept it? That is the preferred format for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The new autocorrelation plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0T8BG.png)

```
p11 <- ggplot(Autokor)+ geom_line(aes(x=Lag, y=0))+ geom_line(aes(y=Kryds_HP_HP, x=Lag, color = "HUSPRIS"), formula = y ~ s(x, k = 11), method = "gam", se = FALSE) + geom_line(aes(y=Kryds_RENTE_RENTE, x=Lag, color = "RENTE"), formula = y ~ s(x, k = 11), method = "gam", se = FALSE) + geom_line(aes(y=Kryds_BNP_BNP, x=Lag, color = "BNP"), formula = y ~ s(x, k = 11), method = "gam", se = FALSE) + geom_line(aes(y=Kryds_KREDIT_KREDIT, x=Lag, color = "KREDIT"), formula = y ~ s(x, k = 11), method = "gam", se = FALSE) + scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",") ,limits = c(-1, 1), breaks=round(seq(min(-1), max(1), by = 0.5),1)) + scale_x_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",") ,limits = c(-6, 6), breaks=round(seq(min(-6), max(6), by = 1),1)) + labs(title = "Autokorrelationer", x="Lag", y="Korrelation", caption = "", color=NULL) + theme(legend.position="bottom") + theme(panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank()) + th
```

The problem was that `stat_smooth()` was to aggressive to approach 1 at lag 0. It therefore solved the problem by replacing `stat_smooth()`, with `geom_line()`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).